# What is the statistical probability to the following real world problem?

Tags: probability, statistics

It's been a while since I last took statistics so I need help verifying my calculations to a real-life practical problem. My wife and I want to do IVF with PGD to get a girl.

The OBGYN at the fertility clinic said the following: typically $8$ eggs are retrieved in each round of IVF. Only half the eggs retrieved are viable due to genetic defects with the other half. Of the half that is viable, there's a $50\%$ it will be fertilized with an X chromosome sperm to get a viable female embryo.

Question: assuming 8 eggs are retrieved in $1$ round of IVF, what are the chances of getting at least 1 viable female embryo.

At the clinic, the OBGYN says the answer is $25\%$. But when I got home I thought it about it and my calculation says $90\%$.

What do you guys think? What are the chances at least $2$ will be viable female embryos?

Comment: At least $1$ or at least $2$?

Comment: At least 1 and at least 2. Stats for both please. Need both to make informed decision.

Answer (score 2):

The probability that a particular egg will end up as a viable female embryo (VFE) is $0.25$ so that the probability of all $8$ not ending up as a VFE is $P_0=0.75^8=0.10011$.  Therefore the probability of at least one VFE is $1-P_0=0.89989$.

To get the probability of at least two VFE, you need to get the probability of exactly one VFE which is $P_1=8\times 0.25\times 0.75^7=0.26696$ Net result $1-P_0-P_1=0.632919$ is the probability of at least two VFE.

Comment: Thanks Herb. This really makes me question the competency of the OBGYN at this clinic, or even doctors in general.

Comment: Hopefully they are decent doctors even if lousy mathematicians.

Comment: Btw, isn't P1=8×0.25×0.75^7 = 0.266968?

Comment: You are right - arithmetic has never been my strong sute.  I've corrected the answer.

Comment: Note that you are assuming the events of getting VFE are independent.  This might or might not be true.

Comment: @ awkward  You are correct.  However without the assumption of independence, more information is needed and it becomes a biology problem not a math problem.